Windows 11 apps showing my location as the wrong country
my laptop is doing this odd thing where it suddenly decides I'm in Australia and changes my timezone to that (I'm not, I'm in the UK). Obviously I can bypass it by manually setting it but I'd rather figure out what's causing the discrepancy. My IP hasn't changed from what it's always been, I don't use a VPN, and my IP address shows correctly as UK on any tool that uses it. Maps in Chrome also shows my location correctly as well, so it's not an IP or GPS thing. The issue is limited to Windows apps - Weather, Maps, Edge. If I open Bing Maps in Edge it shows me in Australia but if I open Bing Maps in Chrome it shows me in the UK. I've tried using Event Viewer and Process Monitor to track down what's going on but it's difficult to narrow down the hundreds of thousands of processes that occur when I click the button. It did briefly fix itself for a few weeks but today the issue returned

@John yes it's all properly set. Have restarted many times since


Open Settings (right-click on the Start symbol and choose Settings)
Search for "region" and click on "region settings"
You should now be in the Time & Language > Language & Region section.
Scroll down to Country or Region and select your location.



This is already set to the UK. Doesn't change anything.
